# darcs: First push fails

Tags: version-control, freebsd, darcs

When I push a patch to a remote repository via ssh, the first try fails with

```
me@bowler$ darcs push
~/Dokumente/Aufsaetze/ar_report
Pushing to "me@somewhere:/home/me/darcs_repos/ar_report"...
Mon Nov 17 10:13:38 CET 2014 me@somewhere.com
  * automatisierung
Shall I push this patch? (1/1)  [ynW...], or ? for more options: a

darcs failed:  Couldn't fetch 0000000369b60776b9ae996a253f8a5a296927293faab87036846b34b0e710c9fc0f58429b'
in subdir inventories from sources:

thisrepo:/usr/home/me/darcs_repos/ar_report
cache:/home/me/.darcs/cache


HINT: I could not reach the following repositories:
    /home/me/.darcs/cache
    /usr/home/me/darcs_repos/ar_report
  If you're not using them, you should probably delete
  the corresponding entries from _darcs/prefs/sources.
Apply failed!
```

The second attempt works without problems. Does someone has a clue what's going on here?

Comment: What's in `_darcs/prefs/sources` and how did it end up that way?

Comment: repo:me@somewhere:/home/me/darcs_repos/ar_report. Came with the get.

Comment: The reference to `/usr/home` looks fishy.  Do you have, or did you use to have, a symlink there?

Comment: This could be the point. It is a FreeBSD box, where the old directory style was /usr/home/USER. I don't have this on my box, but there might be some legacy code. I'll go after that.

Comment: correction: /home is a symlink to /usr/home. I changed the sources file to /usr/home/me/darcs_repos/ar_report. Same problem. Maybe a cache file somewhere?

Comment: Does this happen for each new patch you try to push? Was either the local or the remote repository made with --lazy (or ^Cing a get)?

Comment: @ganesh-sittampalam It happens for each new patch. No lazy-get and no interrupted get. I just tested it. I am not sure, but it could be a problem with the symlink. The thing is: Why does the second attempt succeed?

Comment: The second attempt succeeding is definitely the strangest aspect. Can you reproduce it if you use `darcs send -O` to write out a `.dpatch` file, copy it to the remote side manually and use `darcs apply` on the file? As the failure is at the remote end, if that does reproduce it, it'll make it simpler to debug.

Comment: This reproduces the failure. Second attempt succeeds. Should I file a bug report?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. Can you include the output of both `darcs apply` commands with `--debug`?

Comment: Done. Bug report filed. For reference: http://bugs.darcs.net/

Comment: I can't actually see this bug there, and your link points to the front page. Did it get submitted properly?

Comment: I submitted it via email on 11/19

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to have got lost - we've checked the moderation system but can't find it :-( Would you mind resending, and copy ganesh@earth.li in case it goes wrong again?

Comment: Yes, sure! and... done.

Comment: For reference, link to the issue: http://bugs.darcs.net/issue2424

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [some investigation](http://bugs.darcs.net/issue2424), this turns out to have gone away in darcs 2.8.5 whereas it was happening in darcs 2.8.4. My best guess is that it was an instance of [this bug](http://bugs.darcs.net/issue2364), but the connection wasn't obvious.